# Curl post response is not returning before if check

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have a curl post that goes to an identity server. I have to post the user's credentials and handle the response that comes back. My problem is that the script continues executing before the response has returned.

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output = array();
$output = json_decode($response,true);//this is not populated before the next line


//if username or password is incorrect
$error = $output["error"];
if(!empty($error)){
    echo "output error var during login";
    echo var_dump($output);// NULL every time
}
```

The code isn't waiting for the curl response so when I check $error in the "if" test, it is NULL every time, even when I type the wrong password. I have a unit test that checks the code and the server is returning the response.

The $output variable does eventually get populated but I read that curl blocks the thread so why would the

Comment: can you provide a var_dump($output) ?

Comment: tthe var_dump of $output is NULL.

Comment: Have you tried to get a `var_dump($output)` before `$error = $output["error"];` statement

Comment: Also check for curl errors by using `curl_error($ch)` after the `curl_exec($ch)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check `$output['error']` is **NOT** `null` to verify an error occurred, you're doing it wrong.

```
if(empty($error)){
```

should be

```
if( ! empty($error)){
```

or alternatively

```
if(isset($error)){
```

Comment: I've done it all those ways, the problem is that $output is completely empty when I do the check and it get populated later.